# Java | repeat of sort list on basis of array value with change in values in array

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

its very difficult making it interesting too as once list sorted with comparator could not be sorted again but this is what we need with change in array values to be sorted as bellow
                //ALL should always on TOP

1. //if 1 is taken then        //mainList of  SortTech to be sorted  ALL , B , A , C, D, E, F ,G
2. //1 was taken now 4 is taken then 
             //mainList of  SortTech to be sorted  ALL, B , E, A , C, D,  F ,G
3. //now 1,4 are dropped and 6,5 taken then             //mainList of  SortTech to be sorted  ALL, G, F, A , B,  C, D, E
4. // 6,5 was taken now -1 is taken then         //mainList of  SortTech to be sorted  ALL, A , B,  C, D, E , F, G

```html
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SortTech {

    private  long id;
    private String name ;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<SortTech> mainList = new ArrayList<>();

        SortTech S1 = new SortTech();
        S1.setName("ALL");
        S1.setId(-1);
        mainList.add(S1);

        SortTech S2 = new SortTech();
         S2.setName("A");
        S2.setId(0);
        mainList.add(S2);


        SortTech S3 = new SortTech();
        S3.setName("B");
        S3.setId(1);
        mainList.add(S3);

        SortTech S4 = new SortTech();
        S4.setName("C");
        S4.setId(2);
        mainList.add(S4);

        SortTech S5 = new SortTech();
        S5.setName("D");
        S5.setId(3);
        mainList.add(S5);

        SortTech S6 = new SortTech();
        S6.setName("E");
        S6.setId(4);
        mainList.add(S6);

        SortTech S7 = new SortTech();
        S7.setName("F");
        S7.setId(5);
        mainList.add(S7);

        SortTech S8 = new SortTech();
        S8.setName("G");
        S8.setId(6);
        mainList.add(S8);


/*     //tried with comparator but it give unmodifiable list in return so could not modify any further 
 *    Collections.sort(mainList, new Comparator<SortTech>() {
            public int compare(SortTech t1, SortTech t2) {
                if (t1.getName().equals("ALL"))
                    return -1;
                if (t2.getName().equals("ALL"))
                    return 1;
                return t2.getName().compareTo(t2.getName());
            }
        });*/


        //ALL should always on TOP 

        //if 1 is taken 
        Long[] taken = new Long[]{(long) 1};
        //mainList of  SortTech to be sorted as ALL , B , A , C, D, E, F ,G
        //system out 

        //1 was taken now 4 is taken  
        taken = new Long[]{(long) 1, (long) (4)};
        //mainList of  SortTech to be sorted as  ALL, B , E, A , C, D,  F ,G
        //system out 

        //now 1,4 are dropped and 6,5 taken 
        taken = new Long[]{(long) 6, (long) (5)};
        //mainList of  SortTech to be sorted as  ALL, G, F, A , B,  C, D, E  
        //system out 

        //now 6,5 was taken now -1 is taken 
        taken = new Long[]{(long) 6, (long) (5), (long) (-1)};
        //mainList of  SortTech to be sorted as  ALL, A , B,  C, D, E , F, G 
        //system out 








    }



    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }



    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



}
```

Comment: Side note you could always write the alphabet into an array, and or string and access each character using an index which matches the id. 

`char[] alphabet = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'...};`

`for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){`
        `SortTech s = new SortTech();`
        `S.setName(alphabet[i]);`
        `S.setId(i);`
        `mainList.add(s);`
`}`

Comment: @Underbalanced thanks for reply , A,B,C  and 0,1,2 are just example taken could be anything like apple, google, or 323,456, also here we are bound to take long array and based on long array value we need to sort list of object

Answer (score 0):

First, create a separate class for your comparator. This is needed because you need a way to give the 'taken' list to the comparator.

```
public class SortTechComparator implements Comparator<SortTech> {

    Array<Long> taken;

    public SortTechComparator<SortTech>(Long[] takenArray) {
        taken = Arrays.asList(takenArray);
    }

    public int compare(SortTech t1, SortTech t2) {
        // 1. if t1 is 'ALL'
        if (t1.getName().equals("ALL"))
            return -1;

        // 2. if t2 is 'ALL'
        if (t2.getName().equals("ALL"))
            return 1;

        // 3. if 'ALL' is not taken
        if (!isItemTaken(-1)) {

            // 4. if one item is in 'taken' list but the other is not
            if (isItemTaken(t1.getId()) != isItemTaken(t2.getId())) {
                return isItemTaken(t1.getId()) ? -1 : 1;
            }

            // 5. if both items are 'taken'
            if (isItemTaken(t1.getId()) && isItemTaken(t2.getId())) {
                return itemPosition(t1.getId()) < itemPosition(t2.getId()) ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }

        // 6. sort based on name
        return t2.getName().compareTo(t2.getName());
    }

    private boolean isItemTaken(long itemId) {
        return taken.contains(itemId);
    }

    private long itemPosition(long itemId) {
        return taken.indexOf(itemId);
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use the comparator to sort:

```
Long[] taken = ...
Collections.sort(mainList, new SortTechComparator(taken));
```

**How it works**

1. This puts 'ALL' first if it is in t1.
2. This puts 'ALL' first if it is in t2.
3. If 'ALL' is taken, then the sort order for everything else should be name based, so skip the 'taken'-based sorting. We invert this test so that we only do the 'taken'-based sorting if 'ALL' is **not** taken.
4. If one item is in the 'taken' list but the other is not, then we can sort according to whether the first is in the 'taken' list.
5. If both items are taken, then sort on position in the 'taken' list.
6. This is the catch-all. If we get here, then we just need a name sort.